# MINDSTORMS 51515 exporting code

Tags: mindstorms, robot-inventor

I have created a MOC that I am going to put on Rebrickable. But the code is so complex I can’t do what I normally do and take a screen shot of the code and they replicate it. Does anyone know how if possible to upload the `.lms` files I found on my iPad to a Windows computer. I have the transfer of the files from iPad to Windows but I don’t have the ability to use a Windows computer to test opening it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an iOS device, but in the Android/ChromeOS version, there is a *Share* option when you click the `⋮` button next to the project name. You can use this to email the project, send it to Dropbox/OneDrive/Google Drive, etc. The exact options will depend on which other apps you have installed. The shared project (`.lms` file) can be opened by others on any OS with the same or newer version of the MINDSTORMS programming app.

[image: screenshot of project menu]

Comment: Ok thanks for the help